# Need some help building a query to get info from several tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this *semi-complex* table structure:

[image]

And I need to return this data:

```
{
  "id": "10111001",
  "rep_id": "30000001",
  "targets_id": "60011001",
  "brands_id": "10010001",
  "brand_name": "Quillivant XR",
  "messages_id": "10111001",
  "message_text": "Thank you for taking time to speak with me today. Based on our discussion, I&apos;ve attached additional materials about Quillivant XR&trade; (methylphenidate HCI) CII. I look forward to following up with you in the near future. Thank you.",
  "media": [
    {
      "media_id": "10011001",
      "title": "Pfizer -- Largest Pharmaceutical Company In T",
      "description": "The New York-based giant is one of the largest pharmaceutical companies in the world, based on revenues. Known for famous drugs like Lipitor and Viagra, Pfizer Inc. (PFE) has acquired several big names over the years including Pharmacia, Warner-Lambert and Wyeth to become one of the world's largest research-based pharmaceutical companies. It has also been the target of lawsuits and has had to settle with the US Department of Justice, four times in the last 10 years.",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/pfizer_logo_detail.gif",
      "viewedAt": "2013-06-27 20:18:33"
    },
    {
      "media_id": "10011002",
      "title": "Proxy Statement for 105 Annual Meeting of Sha",
      "description": "A proxy statement is a statement required of a firm when soliciting shareholder votes. This statement is filed in advance of the annual meeting. The firm needs to file a proxy statement, otherwise known as a Form DEF 14A (Definitive Proxy Statement), with the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission.",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/pfizer_logo_detail.gif",
      "viewedAt": "2013-06-27 20:18:33"
    }
  ],
  "category": "sent",
  "createdAt": "2013-06-27 20:18:33",
  "openedAt": "2013-06-27 20:18:33",
  "viewedAt": "2013-06-27 20:18:33"
}
```

As you can see from `targets` to `reps` all the tables are almost involve on the result. I started this query:

```
SELECT brands.id, brands.name, targets.id, reps.id, messages.* FROM messages WHERE reps.id = :rid LIMIT 10
```

But I don't know how to properly do the FROM clause and/or how to order the JOINS and if will be better to use LEFT or just JOIN. Also I am not sure if I can get every media for each row or I need to separate that into two queries. Can any help me to build this queries to get the expected output?

Comment: Hope this helps: SELECT 
messages.id AS messages_id, 
messages.message_text, 
brands.name AS brand_name, 
companies.name AS companies_names 
FROM 
messages 
LEFT JOIN brands on messages.brands_id = brands.id 
LEFT JOIN companies on brands.companies_id = companies.id